# inequality between 3 square roots

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm breaking my head over this. If (a,b,c) are positive real, show that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{2a}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{c+a}}\le3
\end{align}

(There is equality only when $a=b=c$)

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193568/inequality-sqrt-frac11a5a6b-sqrt-frac11b5b6c-sqrt-frac11c)