# Prove inequality $\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+a}} + \sqrt{\frac{2b}{c+b}} + \sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+c}} \leq 3$

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

How to prove the following inequality :
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+a}} + \sqrt{\frac{2b}{c+b}} + \sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+c}} \leq 3
$$
with $a>0,\  b>0$ and $c>0$.

Comment: @Gaffney, then we would get $1 + 0 + \sqrt{2} \le 3$, which seems correct.

Comment: Looks [familiar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192947/inequality-sqrt-frac2abc-sqrt-frac2bca-sqrt-frac2cab-l).

Answer (score 5):

since $$9(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)\ge 8(ab+bc+ac)(a+b+c)$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\dfrac{2a}{a+b}}\le\sqrt{\left[\sum(c+a)\right]\left[\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{2a}{(a+b)(c+a)}\right]}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ac)}{(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)}}\le 3$$